# Is Gradient Boosting a particular algorithm of Any Boost?

Tags: machine-learning, boosting, ensemble-learning

Any Boost is describe as follows:

[image]

I haven't ever seen a inner product as stop criteria in Gradient Boosting algorithm. In Any Boost the weak learner is a function $f_{t+1}$ that maximizes inner product between Gradient and $f$ while in Gradient Boosting it is a function that estimes the gradient of previous model. I'd like to know if gradient boosting could be view as a particular case of Any Boost since there is a convergence theory for Any Boost.